# How to rename custom module in prestashop

Tags: php, symfony, prestashop, prestashop-modules

I have developed a custom module and install it from back office.lately i got a requirement to change the module name.

I tried these steps.

1. Uninstall my module
2. Rename my module folder name (my_shipping -> shipping_module )
3. Rename module file under modules folder (my_shipping.php ->
   shipping_module)
4. Rename class name and __construct name

Then i have refresh my back office module selection and i saw it under `installed modules` tab.(but i've started these steps when uninstall it).then i tried to uninstall it .then it show me

> cannot uninstall module xxx . the module is not installed.

How to rename my existing custom module?

```
class Shipping_module extends CarrierModule
{
    protected $config_form = false;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name          = 'shipping_module';
        $this->tab           = 'shipping_logistics';
        $this->version       = '1.0.0';
        $this->author        = 'DDD';
        $this->need_instance = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems like it wasn't uninstalled at the step #1 because of some error.

Try this steps.

1. Rename it back as it originally was then uninstall and remove it (there is a tick box to remove the module after uninstalling it).
2. Once you are sure it was removed rename it with the new name, folder, class and every occurrence of the class name in the module files.
3. Install the module again; keep the Debug mode to ON so you can see any error that might appear.

Answer (score 1):

Options:

1. Delete module folder in /modules/moduletodelete
2. Go to the module main file (class) and try to run "uninstall" function.
3. If you liketo rename module you need to run try next code:

   ```
    $this->name = 'custom';
    $this->tab = 'custom';
    $this->version = '0.0.1';
    $this->author = 'custom';
    $this->need_instance = 0;
    $this->add();//or $this->save;
   ```

Example for point 2: Goto /modules/moduletodelete/moduletodelete.php, check how called uninstall function (something like "public function uninstall()") and try to run next code:

```
$this->[name_of_uninstall()]; //example $this->uninstall();
```